# How to append element height as other element style value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

i have a little problem with my script. I want to get height of some element and this var/value as top position in css for other element. This is my code:

```
 var lb_img_size = $('.lb_photo_panel img').height();
 $('.lb_close_button').css('top', lb_img_size + 'px');
```

Comment: your code seems right, what problem do you have with it?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Is the image loaded, otherwise height will return absolutely nothing?

Comment: Just for fun, see if this works : http://jsfiddle.net/YFdh5/1/

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if you set `.lb_close_button`'s `position` css property to absolute

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$('.lb_close_button').css('top',$('.lb_photo_panel img').css('height'));
```

Comment: just a way of assigning css property of one element to css property of another element.thats what he's asking.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski:have u written the above function on `pageload` event?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski:It'll only work when elements on your page gets rendered on it.

Comment: so, i need to set some Timeout?

Comment: great..! But it wont work if page loading will take lot of time.i will suggest you to use it inside `pageload`.no matter how much time it take to render,its definitely gonna work.

Comment: ok, thx for suggest, this may be better solution for this, thx again, chears